# My project only work with iPhone 6 but not iPhone 6 plus and other size of iPhone ( in iOS Simulator) Why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have made a project everything finished. I also set the constraint. But when I test it only work with iPhone 6. In the beginning I thought that because of the constraint setting. But it isn´t. Can somebody tell me what happen ?

Comment: Add some images, code etc to explain what is wrong

Comment: Seriously though. With the amount of information provided (i.e. none at all) it isn't possible to diagnose any problems or help fix them.

Comment: I know,  me too I don´t really know what is this. hmm saddd.

Comment: To Fogmeister and Azat. I am not able to add image here.
Code ? it´s not about code at all as long as everything just work fine with the code. The problem here is just everything is not apear when I test with other size of iPhone in iOS simulator...ANd My thought is just I´m not sure if this is because something wrong with setting that I don´t know yet.

Comment: As I know you can add links at comments

Comment: Here is the link to example image
[Link to example](http://www.thaimarked.com/test.html)
As you can see in iPhone6 plus (and other model) appear nothing from my code. DOn´t know what happen.

Comment: Please post code for that view controller

Comment: I have update the post, and the ViewController is there

Comment: Seems like you just missing database file except iPhone 6 simulator

Comment: Does database file work only with iPhone6 ? Then what should I do ?

Comment: Do you think this is the bug in Xcode ?

Comment: what error are you getting when running in iPhone 4, 4s, 5, 5s ???

Comment: Try logging and see where the problem is that way.

Comment: I have no idea to find what kind of logging i should do when it works fine without any problem with iPhone6 simulator but not other models. Is there are some way to do log like that ? Tell me.

Comment: I believe there is a bug in xcode 6.3.1for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem. 
In each model of iOs Simulator, there are difference folder which store database for each of them and update it. I need to put the database files to every folder. I n this case I only have database inside  ios Simulator for iPhone6 that why the other models could not find the datase. This is what I have learnt today. In the beginning I thought Xcode will do the jobb for me. hmmm but now I am happy.

Comment: This is not a good solution. How do you plan to do this on every device that runs your app?

Comment: This is just the test project. And I am new with objective-c and xcode. What is the best solution ? can you tell me ? 
I can see..When I run from a model to another model, there are new folder for its database. ANd If I do not update it, I will get wrong database. I need to be finished all with database( I use firefox to manage .sqlite file) then Put it in every model database folder. Is that not correct ? But anyway, I think I understand correct. But I solved my problem.